# Getting errno: 150 in MySQL while trying to use composite keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to both this site and databases. I am creating a database for a point of sale for a company. Im having problems since I have so many composite primary keys okay so here is my question... I have the table member:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS member;
CREATE TABLE member (
    fName                   varchar(10)      NOT NULL,
    lname                   varchar(10)      NOT NULL,
    shippingAddress         varchar(50)      NOT NULL,
    billingAddress          varchar(50)      NOT NULL,
    memberNo                varchar(15)      NOT NULL,
    memStartDate            date             NOT NULL,
    memOf                   varchar(15)      ,
    PRIMARY KEY(memberNo, shippingAddress)
);
 and table shipping:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shipping;
CREATE TABLE shipping (
       company           varchar(10)    NOT NULL,
       warehouseAddress  varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
       memberAddress     varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
       memberNum         varchar(15)    NOT NULL,
       orderNumber       varchar(20)    NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY(orderNumber)
);

ALTER TABLE shipping ADD CONSTRAINT shipping_memberAddnNUM_refs_member_memberNoNshippingAddress FOREIGN KEY (memberAddress, memberNum)
      REFERENCES member (shippingAddress, memberNo);
```

So it gives me an errno: 150

I dont necessarily need member(shippingAddress) to be part of the primary key. But i do need to reference it my shipping table. Does anyone know how to get past this I have been looking at examples online but none of them seem to fix it.

Comment: You need to spend some time looking around the site and seeing how it works.  Does anyone else post their title in ALL CAPS?  Do you see how everyone puts their code in grey blocks? (indent 4 spaces).

Comment: There are several criteria to be met for creating a foreign key.

Comment: The key is `(memberNo, shippingAddress)` so keep the foreign key in that order too

Comment: And why is the primary key composite? Isn't the `memberNo` unique?

Comment: Thank you Damir works now, Thank you Robert for fixing my formatting as soon as I posted I tried fixing but was unable to because you already had so I thank you. Like I said im new to this site but the response time and accuracy is outstanding

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
CONSTRAINT      NAME_OF_PK      PRIMARY KEY(Field1, Field2)
```

But this is Microsoft's SQL way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two columns in reverse order - from how they appear in the `PRIMARY KEY` of `member`. Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE shipping 
  ADD CONSTRAINT shipping_memberAddnNUM_refs_member_memberNoNshippingAddress 
   FOREIGN KEY (memberNum, memberAddress)
     REFERENCES member (memberNo, shippingAddress);
```